# Doctrine ODM EmbedOne to EmbedMany

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

I use Mongodb with Doctrine2 to log actions on appointments fot stats purpose. I had to modify the Entity from

```
class Appointment {
  /** @ODM\Id */
  protected $id;
  /** @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Product") */
  private $product;
to
class Appointment {
  /** @ODM\Id */
  protected $id;
  /** @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Product") */
  private $products;
```

So earlier one appointment had one product, but now one appointment may have multiple products. Every things work fine while saving.
My question is how do I update the old documents 'product' to put them also into an array?

Regards Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You can use the migration features described here: http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/migrating-schemas.html

In your case, you can update your Doctrine document this way:

```
<?php
class Appointment
{
    /**
     * ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Product")
     * @ODM\NotSaved
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Product")
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @ODM\AlsoLoad({"product"})
     */
    public function populateProducts($product)
    {
        $this->products = [$product];
        $this->product = null;
    }

    /**
     * @ODM\AlsoLoad({"product"})
     */
    public function populateProducts($product)
    {
        $this->products = [$product];
    }
}
```

This way, the old single product is cast to a collection of products.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Have still a question based on your answer: do I have to loop through all document and launch populateProducts($product) ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to loop through all documents ans persist them again. However, you don't have to call populateProducts yourself, as Doctrine ODM does it automatically for you when the document is loaded.

Comment: Hi, I tried everything but an error is raising:  Array to string conversion in ApplicationEntityDocumentsAppointmentHydrator where we have
    if (isset($data['product'])) {
            $value = $data['product'];
            $return = (string) $value;
            $this->class->reflFields['product']->setValue($document, $return);
            $hydratedData['product'] = $return;
        } It is the $return = (string) $value; causing the error

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? And can you show your entity? Maybe you have not generated correctly the getters and setters. Remove them all and run the `app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents` command again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity\Documents;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="appointment")
 */
class Appointment {

    /** @ODM\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @ODM\String @ODM\Index */
    protected $department;

    /** @ODM\String @ODM\Index */
    protected $action;

    /** @ODM\Int @ODM\Index */
    protected $idAppointment;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $service_order;

    /** @ODM\Int */
    protected $sales_order;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $access_number;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $so_type;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $stage;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $se_items;

    /** @ODM\String @ODM\Index */
    protected $id_va;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $id_icms;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $company;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $customer_name;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $street;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $housenumber;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $building;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $appartment;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $postal_code;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $city;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $email;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $contact_number;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $ref_isp;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $comment;

    /** @ODM\Date */
    protected $first_available_schedule;

    /** @ODM\Date */
    protected $request_cancellation;

    /** @ODM\Boolean */
    protected $asap;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $allday;

    /** @ODM\String @ODM\Index */
    protected $operator;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $createdBy;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $movedBy;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $network;

    /** @ODM\Date @ODM\Index */
    private $created;

    /** @ODM\Date @ODM\Index */
    private $posted;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $actionBy;

    /** @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Schedule") */
    private $schedule;

    /**
     * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Product")
     * @ODM\NotSaved
     */
    protected $product;

    /** @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Product") */
    private $products = array();

    /**
     * @ODM\AlsoLoad({"product"})
     */
    public function populateProducts($product) {
        $this->products = [$product];
        $this->product = null;
    }

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $mqMsg;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDepartment() {
        return $this->department;
    }

    public function getAction() {
        return $this->action;
    }

    public function getIdAppointment() {
        return $this->idAppointment;
    }

    public function getService_order() {
        return $this->service_order;
    }

    public function getSales_order() {
        return $this->sales_order;
    }

    public function getAccess_number() {
        return $this->access_number;
    }

    public function getSo_type() {
        return $this->so_type;
    }

    public function getStage() {
        return $this->stage;
    }

    public function getSe_items() {
        return $this->se_items;
    }

    public function getId_va() {
        return $this->id_va;
    }

    public function getId_icms() {
        return $this->id_icms;
    }

    public function getCompany() {
        return $this->company;
    }

    public function getCustomer_name() {
        return $this->customer_name;
    }

    public function getStreet() {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function getHousenumber() {
        return $this->housenumber;
    }

    public function getBuilding() {
        return $this->building;
    }

    public function getAppartment() {
        return $this->appartment;
    }

    public function getPostal_code() {
        return $this->postal_code;
    }

    public function getCity() {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getContact_number() {
        return $this->contact_number;
    }

    public function getRef_isp() {
        return $this->ref_isp;
    }

    public function getComment() {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function getFirst_available_schedule() {
        return $this->first_available_schedule;
    }

    public function getRequest_cancellation() {
        return $this->request_cancellation;
    }

    public function getAsap() {
        return $this->asap;
    }

    public function getAllday() {
        return $this->allday;
    }

    public function getOperator() {
        return $this->operator;
    }

    public function getCreatedBy() {
        return $this->createdBy;
    }

    public function getMovedBy() {
        return $this->movedBy;
    }

    public function getNetwork() {
        return $this->network;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getPosted() {
        return $this->posted;
    }

    public function getActionBy() {
        return $this->actionBy;
    }

    public function getSchedule() {
        return $this->schedule;
    }

    public function getProduct() {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function getMqMsg() {
        return $this->mqMsg;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setDepartment($department) {
        $this->department = $department;
    }

    public function setAction($action) {
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function setIdAppointment($idAppointment) {
        $this->idAppointment = $idAppointment;
    }

    public function setService_order($service_order) {
        $this->service_order = $service_order;
    }

    public function setSales_order($sales_order) {
        $this->sales_order = $sales_order;
    }

    public function setAccess_number($access_number) {
        $this->access_number = $access_number;
    }

    public function setSo_type($so_type) {
        $this->so_type = $so_type;
    }

    public function setStage($stage) {
        $this->stage = $stage;
    }

    public function setSe_items($se_items) {
        $this->se_items = $se_items;
    }

    public function setId_va($id_va) {
        $this->id_va = $id_va;
    }

    public function setId_icms($id_icms) {
        $this->id_icms = $id_icms;
    }

    public function setCompany($company) {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    public function setCustomer_name($customer_name) {
        $this->customer_name = $customer_name;
    }

    public function setStreet($street) {
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    public function setHousenumber($housenumber) {
        $this->housenumber = $housenumber;
    }

    public function setBuilding($building) {
        $this->building = $building;
    }

    public function setAppartment($appartment) {
        $this->appartment = $appartment;
    }

    public function setPostal_code($postal_code) {
        $this->postal_code = $postal_code;
    }

    public function setCity($city) {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setContact_number($contact_number) {
        $this->contact_number = $contact_number;
    }

    public function setRef_isp($ref_isp) {
        $this->ref_isp = $ref_isp;
    }

    public function setComment($comment) {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    public function setFirst_available_schedule($first_available_schedule) {
        $this->first_available_schedule = $first_available_schedule;
    }

    public function setRequest_cancellation($request_cancellation) {
        $this->request_cancellation = $request_cancellation;
    }

    public function setAsap($asap) {
        $this->asap = $asap;
    }

    public function setAllday($allday) {
        $this->allday = $allday;
    }

    public function setOperator($operator) {
        $this->operator = $operator;
    }

    public function setCreatedBy($createdBy) {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;
    }

    public function setMovedBy($movedBy) {
        $this->movedBy = $movedBy;
    }

    public function setNetwork($network) {
        $this->network = $network;
    }

    public function setCreated($created) {
        $this->created = $created;
    }

    public function setPosted($posted) {
        $this->posted = $posted;
    }

    public function setActionBy($actionBy) {
        $this->actionBy = $actionBy;
    }

    public function setSchedule($schedule) {
        $this->schedule = $schedule;
    }

    public function setProduct($product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function setProducts($products) {
        $this->products = $products;
    }

    public function setMqMsg($mqMsg) {
        $this->mqMsg = $mqMsg;
    }

    public function addProduct($product) {
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }

}
```

```
/** @ODM\EmbeddedDocument */
class Schedule {

    /** @ODM\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $layer;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $team;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $disponibility;

    /** @ODM\Date @ODM\Index */
    protected $duedate;

    /** @ODM\Date @ODM\Index */
    protected $dueperiod;

    /** @ODM\Boolean */
    protected $is_task;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getLayer() {
        return $this->layer;
    }

    function getTeam() {
        return $this->team;
    }

    function getDisponibility() {
        return $this->disponibility;
    }

    function getDuedate() {
        return $this->duedate;
    }

    function getDueperiod() {
        return $this->dueperiod;
    }

    function getIs_task() {
        return $this->is_task;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setLayer($layer) {
        $this->layer = $layer;
    }

    function setTeam($team) {
        $this->team = $team;
    }

    function setDisponibility($disponibility) {
        $this->disponibility = $disponibility;
    }

    function setDuedate($duedate) {
        $this->duedate = $duedate;
    }

    function setDueperiod($dueperiod) {
        $this->dueperiod = $dueperiod;
    }

    function setIs_task($is_task) {
        $this->is_task = $is_task;
    }

}
```

```
/** @ODM\EmbeddedDocument */
class Product {

    /** @ODM\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $category;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $disponibility;

    /** @ODM\String */
    protected $abbr;

    /** @ODM\Float */
    protected $freeze_day;

    /** @ODM\Boolean */
    protected $regulated;

    /** @ODM\Int */
    protected $sla;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getCategory() {
        return $this->category;
    }

    function getDisponibility() {
        return $this->disponibility;
    }

    function getAbbr() {
        return $this->abbr;
    }

    function getFreeze_day() {
        return $this->freeze_day;
    }

    function getSenumber() {
        return $this->senumber;
    }

    function getRegulated() {
        return $this->regulated;
    }

    public function getSla() {
        return $this->sla;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setCategory($category) {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    function setDisponibility($disponibility) {
        $this->disponibility = $disponibility;
    }

    function setAbbr($abbr) {
        $this->abbr = $abbr;
    }

    function setFreeze_day($freeze_day) {
        $this->freeze_day = $freeze_day;
    }

    function setSenumber($senumber) {
        $this->senumber = $senumber;
    }

    function setRegulated($regulated) {
        $this->regulated = $regulated;
    }

    public function setSla($sla) {
        $this->sla = $sla;
    }

}
```